# How to display properties of button in parent java plugin?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have a Composite parent, contain some button, I want to display info of button on Properties View. I find several solution

```
getSite().setSelectionProvider(viewer);
```

but viewer such as ListView, TableViewer, vv is ISelectProvider => parent is not a ISelectProvider, so I dont know how to implement. Please help me?

**ButtonElementProperties.java**

```
public class ButtonElementProperties implements IPropertySource {
    final protected ButtonElement element;

    protected static final String PROPERTY_FONT = "font";   
    protected static final String PROPERTY_SIZE = "size";   
    protected static final String PROPERTY_TEXT = "text";   


    private final Object PropertiesTable[][] = {
            { PROPERTY_FONT, new FontPropertyDescriptor(PROPERTY_FONT, "Font") },
            { PROPERTY_SIZE, new PropertyDescriptor(PROPERTY_SIZE, "Size") },
            { PROPERTY_TEXT, new TextPropertyDescriptor(PROPERTY_TEXT, "Text") }, 
            };  

    String strFont = "";
    Point ptSize = null;
    String strText = "";

    protected void firePropertyChanged(String propName, Object value) {
        Button ctl = element.getControl();

        if (ctl == null) {
            // the GUIView is probably hidden in this case
            return;
        }

        if (propName.equals(PROPERTY_FONT)) {
            /**
            Font oldfont = ctl.getFont();
            if (oldfont != null) {
                oldfont.dispose();
            }
            **/
            ctl.setFont(new Font (ctl.getDisplay(),new FontData((String)value)) );
            return;
        }
        if (propName.equals(PROPERTY_TEXT)) {
            ctl.setText((String)value);
            return;
        }

    }

    protected void initProperties() {
        Button ctl = element.getControl();

        if (ctl == null) {
            // the GUIView is probably hidden in this case
            return;
        }

        strText = ctl.getText();
        /**
        Font font = ctl.getFont();
        if (font != null) {
            strFont = font.getFontData().toString();
        }
        **/
        ptSize = ctl.getSize();     
    }


    /**
     * Creates a new ButtonElementProperties.
     *
     * @param element  the element whose properties this instance represents
     */
    public ButtonElementProperties(ButtonElement element) {
        super();
        this.element = element;
        initProperties();
    }

    /**
     * @see org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.IPropertySource#getEditableValue()
     */
    public Object getEditableValue() {
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @see org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.IPropertySource#getPropertyDescriptors()
     */
    public IPropertyDescriptor[] getPropertyDescriptors() {
        // Create the property vector.
        IPropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescriptors = new IPropertyDescriptor[PropertiesTable.length];

        for (int i=0;i<PropertiesTable.length;i++) {                
            // Add each property supported.

            PropertyDescriptor descriptor;

            descriptor = (PropertyDescriptor)PropertiesTable[i][1];
            propertyDescriptors[i] = (IPropertyDescriptor)descriptor;
            descriptor.setCategory("Basic");
        }

        // Return it.
        return propertyDescriptors;

    }

    /**
     * @see org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.IPropertySource#getPropertyValue(Object)
     */
    public Object getPropertyValue(Object name) {
        if (name.equals(PROPERTY_FONT))
            return strFont;
        if (name.equals(PROPERTY_SIZE))
            return new SizePropertySource(element,ptSize);
        if (name.equals(PROPERTY_TEXT))
            return strText;

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @see org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.IPropertySource#isPropertySet(Object)
     */
    public boolean isPropertySet(Object id) {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @see org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.IPropertySource#resetPropertyValue(Object)
     */
    public void resetPropertyValue(Object id) {
    }

    /**
     * @see org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.IPropertySource#setPropertyValue(Object, Object)
     */
    public void setPropertyValue(Object name, Object value) {
        firePropertyChanged((String)name,value);

        if (name.equals(PROPERTY_FONT)) {
            strFont = (String)value;    
            return;
        }
        if (name.equals(PROPERTY_TEXT)) {
            strText = (String)value;    
            return;
        }
        if (name.equals(PROPERTY_SIZE)) {
            SizePropertySource sizeProp = (SizePropertySource)value;            
            ptSize = sizeProp.getValue();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Returns the mocha element.
     * @return MochaElement
     */
    public ButtonElement getButtonElement() {
        return element;
    }

}
```

**ButtonElement.java**

```
 public class ButtonElement implements IWorkbenchAdapter,IAdaptable {
        private String headingName;
        private Button ctl;

        /**
         * Creates a new MarkElement and stores parent element and
         * location in the text.
         *
         * @param parent  the parent of this element
         * @param heading text corresponding to the heading
         * @param offset  the offset into the Readme text
         * @param length  the length of the element
         */
        public ButtonElement(Button initBtn, String heading) {
            this.headingName = heading;
            this.ctl = initBtn;
        }

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * Method declared on IAdaptable
         */
        public Object getAdapter(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Class adapter) {
            if (adapter == IWorkbenchAdapter.class)
                return this;
            if (adapter == IPropertySource.class)
                return new ButtonElementProperties(this);
            return null;
        }
        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * Method declared on IWorkbenchAdapter
         */
        public ImageDescriptor getImageDescriptor(Object object) {
            return null;
        }
        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * Method declared on IWorkbenchAdapter
         */
        public String getLabel(Object o) {
            return headingName;
        }
        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * Method declared on IWorkbenchAdapter
         */
        public Object getParent(Object o) {
            return null;
        }

        public Button getControl() {
            return ctl;
        }
        /**
         * @see org.eclipse.ui.model.IWorkbenchAdapter#getChildren(Object)
         */
        public Object[] getChildren(Object o) {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

**AdaptableList.java**

```
public class AdaptableList implements IWorkbenchAdapter, IAdaptable {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    protected List children = new ArrayList();
/**
 * Creates a new adaptable list with the given children.
 */
public AdaptableList() {
}
/**
 * Creates a new adaptable list with the given children.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public AdaptableList(IAdaptable[] newChildren) {
    for (int i = 0; i < newChildren.length; i++) {
        children.add(newChildren[i]);
    }
}
/**
 * Adds all the adaptable objects in the given enumeration to this list.
 * Returns this list.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public AdaptableList add(Iterator iterator) {
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        add((IAdaptable)iterator.next());
    }
    return this;
}
/**
 * Adds the given adaptable object to this list.
 * Returns this list.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public AdaptableList add(IAdaptable adaptable) {
    children.add(adaptable);
    return this;
}
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * Method declared on IAdaptable
 */
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public Object getAdapter(Class adapter) {
    if (adapter == IWorkbenchAdapter.class) return this;
    return null;
}
/**
 * Returns the elements in this list.
 */
public Object[] getChildren() {
    return children.toArray();
}
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * Method declared on IWorkbenchAdapter
 */
public Object[] getChildren(Object o) {
    return children.toArray();
}
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * Method declared on IWorkbenchAdapter
 */
public ImageDescriptor getImageDescriptor(Object object) {
    return null;
}
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * Method declared on IWorkbenchAdapter
 */
public String getLabel(Object object) {
    return object == null ? "" : object.toString(); //$NON-NLS-1$
}
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * Method declared on IWorkbenchAdapter
 */
public Object getParent(Object object) {
    return null;
}
/**
 * Removes the given adaptable object from this list.
 */
public void remove(IAdaptable adaptable) {
    children.remove(adaptable);
}
/**
 * Returns the number of items in the list
 */
public int size() {
    return children.size();
}
}
```

===> I have Multi Page Editor, and page 1 I call this view **LayoutViewManager**

```
/**

 * Creates page 1 of the multi-page editor,
 * Layout
 */
void createPage1() {

    final Composite composite = new Composite(getContainer(), SWT.NONE);
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
    composite.setLayout(layout);

    LayoutViewManager v = new LayoutViewManager();
    v.createPartControl(composite);

    int index = addPage(composite);

    setPageText(index, "Layout");
}
```

When I drag drop item to this view I want to show some info of button (font, size, text) on properties view, but this code not work, getSite() return null,  how to I can implement it???

**LayoutViewManager**

```
public class LayoutViewManager extends ViewPart {

    public static String LAYOUT_VIEW_ID = "customplugin.views.layoutView";
    private Label label;
    private Group grp1;
    private AdaptableList ctlList;
    private ListViewer viewer;
    public LayoutViewManager() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(final Composite parent) {
        //final Composite container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        RowLayout rowLayout = new RowLayout();
        parent.setLayout(rowLayout);
        createDropTarget(parent);
        /*
        viewer = new ListViewer(parent, SWT.SINGLE );   
        Button btn = new Button(parent, SWT.BORDER);
        ctlList = new AdaptableList();
        ButtonElement btnEl = new ButtonElement(btn,"dd");
        ctlList = new AdaptableList();
        ctlList.add(btnEl);

        viewer.setContentProvider(new BaseWorkbenchContentProvider());
        viewer.setLabelProvider(new WorkbenchLabelProvider());
        viewer.setInput(ctlList); */
        // getSite().setSelectionProvider(viewer);


    }
//    private static final class SelProvider implements ISelectionProvider {
//          protected IStructuredSelection projectSelection = StructuredSelection.EMPTY;
//          private ISelectionProvider selProvider;
//
//          public void addSelectionChangedListener(
//                  ISelectionChangedListener listener) {
//              // do nothing
//          }
//
//          public ISelection getSelection() {
////                return new StructuredSelection(new Button(, 0));
//          }
//
//          public void removeSelectionChangedListener(
//                  ISelectionChangedListener listener) {
//              // do nothing
//          }
//
//          public void setSelection(ISelection selection) {
//              // do nothing
//          }
//      }

    /**
     * create drop target
     * @param parent
     */
    public void createDropTarget (final Composite parent) {
        //  // Allow data to be copied or moved to the drop target
        int operations = DND.DROP_MOVE | DND.DROP_COPY | DND.DROP_DEFAULT;
        DropTarget target = new DropTarget(parent, operations);

        // Receive data in Text or File format
        Transfer[] types = new Transfer[] { TextTransfer.getInstance() };
        target.setTransfer(types);
        target.addDropListener(new DropTargetListener() {

            @Override
            public void dropAccept(DropTargetEvent event) {
            }

            @Override
            public void drop(DropTargetEvent event) {
                 String data = (String) event.data;
                 System.out.print(data);

                if (data.equalsIgnoreCase("TextView")) {
                    Label label = new Label(parent, SWT.BORDER);
                    label.setText(data);
                } else if (data.equalsIgnoreCase("Button")) {
                    Button btn = new Button(parent, SWT.BORDER);
                    btn.setText(data);
//                  ButtonElement btnEl = new ButtonElement(btn,data);
//                  ctlList.add(btnEl);
                 }
                 parent.pack();
                 parent.layout(true);


            }

            @Override
            public void dragOver(DropTargetEvent event) {
            }

            @Override
            public void dragOperationChanged(DropTargetEvent event) {
            }

            @Override
            public void dragLeave(DropTargetEvent event) {
            }

            @Override
            public void dragEnter(DropTargetEvent event) {
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public Object getAdapter(Class adapter) {
        return super.getAdapter(adapter);
    }
    @Override
    public void setFocus() {
        viewer.getControl().setFocus();
    }
    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        super.dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: So write your own ISelectionProvder.

Comment: can you explan for me? how to I can maje ISelectionProvider contain buttons?

Comment: `ViewPart` is only intended to be used as a view declared with the `org.eclipse.ui.views` extension point, it will not function properly embedded in an editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your own selection provider, something like:

```java
class SelProvider implements ISelectionProvider {

    public ISelection getSelection() {
        return new StructuredSelection(button information you want as the selection);
    }

    public void addSelectionChangedListener(ISelectionChangedListener listener) {
        // do nothing
    }

    public void removeSelectionChangedListener(ISelectionChangedListener listener) {
        // do nothing
    }

    public void setSelection(ISelection selection) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

You only need to implement the `getSelection` method.

Comment: sorry, but I dont know how to implement this code  "return new StructuredSelection(button information you want as the selection);"?? I want when I click the button on composite, then it show info on property view?

Comment: plz help me implement it?

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to do. What are you using for `IPropertySource` in your view / editor? What data is it you want to show?